# Can't boot Ubuntu USB - "Invalid magic number"

Tags: system-installation, live-usb

I've tried to install ubuntu from Flash Drive in Windows 10. I'm using Universal Usb Installer app to create a bootable flash drive. The problem is when I boot it through UEFI boot mode and try to install Ubuntu, it says:

```
Error: Invalid magic number
Error: you need to load kernel first
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

1. If you didn't already, try creating the USB drive itself with [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/).
2. Try step #1 with another USB drive if possible.

Comment: It didn't work, after creating the bootable with rufus, it doesn't detect the efi mode in my boot setup, I have checking the file and all file missing in this folder like isolinux, efi, and some more, so I'm using another app, it's work but the result is like what I asked

Comment: I can't understand what you're saying, and it doesn't sound like you tried another USB drive.

Answer (score -1):

Use balenaEtcher to flash your usb maybe? https://balena.io/etcher/